# CSS z-index glitchy layers

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a landing page with an embedded video background so I've assigned its z-index lower than that of the navigation bar, the footer, etc. But when I do so, the layers on top of the video are very glitchy meaning they sometimes don't show up. I thought I could resolve this glitch by assigning the video a negative z-index. This works and solves the glitching problem, but the video layer becomes un-clickable. Not sure what the problem is, really appreciate the help.

### HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:30px;">
        <a href="{{store_url}}">
            {{#logotype}}
            <img src="{{url-2000}}" alt="{{store_name}}">
                {{/logotype}}
        </a>
    </ul>
    <ul style="display: inline-block;">
        <li><a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/all">All</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/men">Men</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/women">Women</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="bg_container">
    <iframe id="bg" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wO_xhHf-OgM?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#bg_container {
    height:700px;
    overflow:visible;
}
#bg {
    width:100%;
    height:1200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    z-index:1;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    padding:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:#000 2px 2px;
}
.transparent {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;
}
.nav {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a demo to showcase your problem, or at least show us the HTML code you are using? This is a shot in the dark, but if it's an embedded video, have you tried setting the `wmode` parameter to `opaque`?

Comment: @Marventus I added the HTML code, wmode is already set to opaque.

Comment: there's a closing `div` tag that has no matching opening tag in your HTML code, right before the closing `nav` tag.

Comment: @Marventus no, just forgot to add it when shortening the code for SO

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code snippet below and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/srgLgyae/).

```css
#bg_container {
    height:700px;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:0;
}
#bg {
    width:100%;
    height:1200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    padding:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:#000 2px 2px;
    z-index:1;
}
nav {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_container">
    <iframe id="bg" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wO_xhHf-OgM?wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="somesite.com"><img class="logo" src="https://chillix.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/android-logo-small.gif" alt="android" /></a>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/all">All</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/men">Men</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://blue-dove.org/products/start-up-collection/women">Women</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```